# How to select window_length and polyorder in scipy.signal.savgol_filter for a daily data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scipy, time-series

Say if I would like to smooth the the following daily data named `oildata` with `scipy.signal.savgol_filter`:

```
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.uniform(0, 10, size=90)
index= pd.date_range('20130226', periods=90)
oildata = pd.Series(data, index)

savgol_filter(oildata, 5, 3)
plt.plot(oildata)
plt.plot(pd.Series(savgol_filter(oildata, 5, 3), index=oildata.index))
plt.show()
```

Out:

[image]

Out:

When I replace `savgol_filter(oildata, 5, 3)` to `savgol_filter(oildata, 31, 3)`:

[image]

Beside trial and error methods, I wonder if there are any criteria or methods to select a suitable `window_length` (which must be a positive odd integer) and `polyorder` (must be less than window_length) pairs quickly? Thanks.

**Reference:**

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.savgol_filter.html